# Knockout datepicker binding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, datepicker

I can not get my datepicker binding working properly.
On initializing the inputsfields are empty.
Does anybody has a proper datepicker handler that set the inputfields with the initial values?

Here is my html code:

```js
function setMappingBindings() {
    obj.myCase(mapCase({ "serviceDate": "2015-09-03T00:00:00", "deadLineDate": "2014-09-16T00:00:00" }));
}
function mapCase(data) {
    var map = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

    map.serviceDate = moment(map.serviceDate()).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
    map.deadLineDate = moment(map.deadLineDate()).format("L");
    return map;
}
var obj = {
    myCase: ko.observable(),
    testDate: ko.observable(moment().format('L')),

};
$(document).ready(function () {
     ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
        $(element).datepicker(options);

        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function (event) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                value(event.date);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
        //when the view model is updated, update the widget
        if (widget) {
            widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (widget.date) {
                widget.setValue();
            }
        }
    }
};

    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    setMappingBindings();
    ko.applyBindings(obj, $("#page-wrapper")[0]);

});
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <input type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-control datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-bind="datepicker: myCase().serviceDate">
</div>
<div class="row">
   <input type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-control datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-bind="datepicker: testDate">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *value* binding on the input tag to have the input set with an initial value.

like so: `value: testDate`

```js
function setMappingBindings() {
    obj.myCase(mapCase({ "serviceDate": "2015-09-03T00:00:00", "deadLineDate": "2014-09-16T00:00:00" }));
}
function mapCase(data) {
    var map = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

    map.serviceDate = moment(map.serviceDate()).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
    map.deadLineDate = moment(map.deadLineDate()).format("L");
    return map;
}
var obj = {
    myCase: ko.observable(),
    testDate: ko.observable(moment().format('L')),

};
$(document).ready(function () {
     ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
        $(element).datepicker(options);

        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function (event) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                value(event.date);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
        //when the view model is updated, update the widget
        if (widget) {
            widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (widget.date) {
                widget.setValue();
            }
        }
    }
};

    setMappingBindings();
    ko.applyBindings(obj, $("#page-wrapper")[0]);

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
   <input type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-control datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-bind="datepicker: myCase().serviceDate, value: myCase().serviceDate">
</div>
<div class="row">
   <input type="text" maxlength="50" class="form-control datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-bind="datepicker: testDate, value: testDate">
</div>
```

Comment: That indeed does work. Unfortunately the datepicker does not popup with the initial date selected and when clicking outside the datepicker the date disappears from the input. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I'd use [moment-datepicker](https://github.com/MakingSense/moment-datepicker). It has a knockout binding handler too.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is rather old question still maybe my experience could help somebody.

I’m using `bootstrap-datepicker` ([link](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) to the product page) in one of my long lasting projects and I did have some problems with `knockout` integration including assigning initial date which is a subject of this topic.

I tried different `ko` custom bindings to the datepicker still it seemed that all of them solving one problem introduced a range of new ones.

Until I encountered this version: http://jsfiddle.net/wtqsgtwm/89/ that seems to work perfectly for all my needs since.

Note that it doesn’t require separate `value` binding to set initial date value. Simple

```
<input type="text" data-bind="datePicker: myDate" >
```

is enough.